# Select all rows of a data.table where a variable is the column name which values are TRUE

Tags: r, dataframe, select, data.table, subset

I have a column name stored in a variable as a string and I need to select all rows of a data.table that have in the column which name I have stored in the variable some specific values.
For the code below I need DT3 to be the same as DT2.

```
> variable<-"V3"
> DT<-data.table(V1=c(1,5,9),V2=c("a","b","c"),V3=c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE))   
> DT2<-DT[V3==TRUE]   
> DT2  
> DT3<-DT[variable==TRUE]    
> DT3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in couple of ways.  Either use `get` to return the value

```
DT3 <- DT[get(variable)]
```

Or convert it to a symbol (`as.name`) and `eval`uate

```
DT3 <- DT[DT[,eval(as.name(variable))]]

identical(DT2, DT3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Note that we don't need to `== TRUE` as 'V3' is already a logical column